# Gradient of colors in a matlab plot

Tags: matlab

I am trying to write a matlab script that would enable me to add color gradient to my 3D plot. I am performing the following test:

> function handle = coloured_line_3d(x, y, z, c)
>
> ```
> handle = surface( [x(:), x(:)], [y(:), y(:)],[z(:), z(:)],[c(:),
> c(:)], 'EdgeColor', 'flat', 'FaceColor', 'none'  );
> end
> ```

```
x = [1; 2; 3]
y = [1; 2; 3]
z = [1; 2; 3]
c = [1 2 3]
```

Running this, the following warnings appear:

```
 coloured_line_3d(x,y,z,c)

ans =
0.0029

Warning: size(CData) must equal size(ZData) or size(ZData)-1 for flat shading 
Warning: size(CData) must equal size(ZData) or size(ZData)-1 for flat shading 
Warning: size(CData) must equal size(ZData) or size(ZData)-1 for flat shading 
Warning: size(CData) must equal size(ZData) or size(ZData)-1 for flat shading
```

and I get an empty plot.

What is wrong with this?

Comment: It works for me (R2013a) - no warnings, just a colored line - but I had to put the `surface` call onto a single line, which I assume is just a SO cut/paste error.

Comment: it was a cut/paste error indeed. I am using R2012b but I can't figure out why it is not working??? or how I could edit the code to make it work (I don't have access to the R2013 version)

Comment: You certain those are the inputs you gave it?

Comment: It also works in R2010b (with the `handle...` in a single line)